# Hash code recursively?

Tags: c, recursion, hash

This should return 451,845,518,507 when I pass in "ice" but it is returning 873,952,427 can anyone tell me why?
(MAX_STR_SIZE = 501)

```
unsigned long hash_code(const char *str){
  char temp[MAX_STR_SIZE]="";
  unsigned long multiplied;
  if(str == NULL){
    return SUCCESS;
  }
  else if(strlen(str)==0 || str==""){
    return SUCCESS;
  }
  else{

      strncpy(temp,str, strlen(str)-1);
      temp[strlen(str)-1]=0;


      multiplied = (hash_code(temp)*65599 + (int) str[strlen(str)-1]);
      return multiplied;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mixing `SUCCESS` and hash values looks suspicious.

Comment: SUCCESS is just a symbol for zero

Comment: Use `*str == '\0'` instead of `str==""`

Comment: why `temp[strlen(str)-1]=0;` ?

Comment: @Jenny Variable names should be meaningful

Comment: Use a debugger. Any other than tail-recursion for such an algorithm is a bad idea. Using tail recursion is just not a good idea. And don't cast unless you 1) have to, 2) understand **all** implications and 3) accept the **fully**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unsigned long` is only 32-bit on your machine.  Need a wider type for 451,845,518,507

```
451,845,518,507 mod pow(2,32) --> 873,952,427
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STR_SIZE 501

unsigned long long hash_code(const char *str){
    char temp[MAX_STR_SIZE] = "";
    unsigned long long hash;
    if(str == NULL ||  strlen(str) == 0 || *str == '\0'){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        strncpy(temp, str, strlen(str) - 1);
        hash = hash_code(temp) * 65599 + str[strlen(str) - 1];
        return hash;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "ice";
    unsigned long long hash;
    hash = hash_code(str);
    printf("%llu", hash);
    return 0;
}
```

You need a `unsigned long long` to contain `451,845,518,507`.